# How do I open new tabs in the Run and Documentation tool windows of IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to open multiple Documentation tabs and also multiple Run tabs at the same time, but I couldn't figure out how. Every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to view documentation, or run a configuration, it always replaces the current tab (screenshot below, here I put Documentation and Run tool windows side-by-side). Is there a way to do this?

[image: Run and Documentation tool windows showing just one tab each]

**EDIT:** I have managed to open another Run tab if I run a different configuration. But can I run the same configuration and have it open in a new tab? (Also the problem about Documentaion tabs remains unsolved.)

Comment: You can pin the existing tab to open the new tab for the same configuration.

Comment: It worked for the Run tab, unfortunately I didn't see a way to pin a Documentation tab.

Comment: It's not supported for the documentation.